# How to insert values in to database in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am working on a joomla 2.5 website & I am trying to insert values in database entered in the form on form submit. But I dont know why they are not inserting in the DB. Please help me out guys.

I've  tried many different ways but I am not getting where I am going wrong.

This is my code:

```
    if(isset($_POST["buttonSubmit"]))
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $location = $_POST["location"]; 
        $email = $_POST["email"];   
        echo $name;
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
        echo $query = "INSERT INTO '#__pxa_map' ('name', 'location','email') VALUES ($name, $location,$email)";
        $db->setQuery( $query );
        $db->query();  
    }
```

How to insert values in to database in joomla 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add error handling and use prepared statements (preferably, don't know how that works in Joomla 2.5), but your query is wrong:

1. You don't quote the table and field names, you escape them with a backtick if necessary;
2. You do quote your values if you don't use a prepared statement;
3. You need to run your input through `$db->quote()` to prevent sql injection.

So it should look like:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$name = $db->quote($_POST["name"]);
// etc.

$query = "INSERT INTO `#__pxa_map` (`name`, `location`,`email`) VALUES ('$name', '$location','$email')";
```

Comment: I tried this also but then also its not working. Can u plz elaborate what u explain above. I am getting it. Please help me out.

Comment: No but is it compulsory? I have retrieve values from database many times but I never used error handling. As u are suggesting to add error handling, I am adding it & lets hope for good. Thanks Jeroen..

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, it works for me. I used this code for error handling: $err = $db->getErrorMsg(); echo $err; And it displays the error.

Comment: @vickram Did the error help you solve the problem, or is it still not working?

Comment: Yes with the error handling I came to know where I was going wrong. And its working fine now. Thanks..